# How to insert text in scanned PDF using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using below code adding text in PDF file. But below code is not working for scanned PDF. Please help me if you have any idea.

```
string oldFile = "C:\\PDF\\Memo1.pdf";
string newFile = "C:\\PDF\\MemoNew1.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
Document document = new Document(size);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
document.Open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
cb.BeginText();
string text = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA...";
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
cb.EndText();
cb.BeginText();
text = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ...";
cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
cb.EndText();
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
document.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"not working"*? That been asked... You first add some text and then cover it with a page from a scanned PDF, and pages of such PDFs usually are page-filling opaque image. Thus, you simply cover your writing with the scanned page...

Comment: I am able to add text in any system generated PDFs. but if I scan any document and convert to a PDF, then same code is not working.

Comment: ... and I just explained why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's code first adds writing to a page canvas

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
cb.BeginText();
string text = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA...";
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
cb.EndText();
cb.BeginText();
text = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ...";
cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
cb.EndText();
```

and then lays an existing page over it:

```
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

Thus, every part of the imported page with opaque content covers what has been written underneath.

In case of a page containing text drawn using text commands, only the actual text is opaque, the "white" around it actually is transparent. If such a page is laid over the OP's writing, most of that writing remains visible.

In case of a page containing a scan, though, there usually is one big, page sized bitmap image in which the "white" actually is an opaque white, not transparent. If such a page is laid over the OP's writing, all of that writing is hidden.

---

There are multiple options to get around this:

- The simplest one: Change the order of instructions, first add the page, then add the writing:

  ```
  PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
  cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
  BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
  cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
  cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
  cb.BeginText();
  string text = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA...";
  cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
  cb.EndText();
  cb.BeginText();
  text = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ...";
  cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
  cb.EndText();
  ```
- Not much more complicated: First set the *blend mode* to **Darken** or **Multiply**, then add in any order. This is done using an *ExtGState*:

  ```
  PdfGState gs1 = new PdfGState();
  gs1.BlendMode = new PdfName("Darken");
  cb.SetGState(gs1);
  ...
  ... add content in any order ...
  ```

Comment: You might want to add that using `PdfWriter` and `PdfImportedPage` to stamp content on an existing PDF is *not done*. The OP should use `PdfStamper` instead. PDFs containing nothing but scanned images aren't a problem, but there might be other PDFs with interactive features, and if @sona 's customer has some of those, sona will have to throw all the code away and start anew.

Comment: Furthermore @sona is using `beginText()`/`endText()` sequences to add text. There are easier ways to add text...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You are right of course. I merely wanted to focus on the main issue, in particular because the OP didn't at all seem to understand what happens. Furthermore, using `PdfWriter` and `PdfImportedPage` is not *always* wrong, merely *more often than not*. Admittedly, considering what we know about the use case at hand, it most likely is wrong here. It makes the second option easier to implement, though... ;) (That been said, I'd really like an advanced feature allowing me to easily prepend content which does have influence on the old content, e.g. for blend modes or to rotate , ...)

Comment: Just changed the order of instructions as explained, and it got worked. Thanks you very much for the kind support.